# Understanding a proof about how counting spanning trees relates to edge deletion and contraction

Tags: graph-theory, trees

qerwn[image]

Can you please explain the essence of the proof? I understood till the underlined statements. After that, I am not able to understand the proof. What does the author do here?

**update on the question. Now I understood that I need to prove the following proposition.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlined text comprises an explanation of the fact that spanning trees of $G \circ e$ are in one-to-one correspondence with spanning trees of $G$ containing $e$ (with each of the former ones being $T \circ e$ for some *unique* $T$ from the latter ones - unique due to $T \neq T' \Rightarrow T \circ e \neq T' \circ e$).

If what you need is a formal proof of that, your way is to a more formal definition of $G \circ e$.

Comment: I have updated my question, the first bijection is an Identity map. Right? How do I prove the second one?

Comment: How do I define the second map? please help me.

Comment: The map is $T \mapsto T/e$ (or $T \circ e$ with the older denotion).

Comment: sorry, initially I couldn't  understand. now, I got your point. Thank you.

Comment: Now, I have got one more doubt, What is the guarantee that  $T\neq T'$ implies $T\circ e$ and $T'\circ e $ different?

Comment: Informally, as both $T$ and $T'$ contain $e$, if $T \neq T'$ then the difference is "somewhere else" (in the rest of vertices or edges), and after the contraction, that difference remains. This is exactly why I started talking on "formalism".

Comment: again thanks.i was thinking wrong

Comment: A final remark is seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree#Deletion-contraction) (regarding multiple edges).